# Send an SMS Message on Server Crash

Tags: sms

Is it possible to send a text or SMS message to my phone when my server crashes?

I know there are services such as TextFree for ipod that allow free texting over wifi but is there anything that can allow a server to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Send an email to the phone's SMS email address. Forex, since I am on Verizon, my SMS email address is *tendigitnumber@vtext.com* . An email to that address will be scooped up by an SMS gateway and translated into an SMS message. A list of SMS email address formats may be found at http://www.emailtextmessages.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here. You could also use [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) to do this.

You can use the Twilio REST API to make a request to send the message - you can even do this simply with a CURL request, so if you don't want to write code but use a shell script, it's super easy:

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account SID}/Messages.json \
    -d "Body=Message" \
    -d "To=receiver" \
    -d "From=sender" \
    -u '{Account SID}:{AuthToken}'
```

You need to URL encode your Message, and set the To/From values to use an appropriate phone number. The sender would typically be a number you can buy from Twilio. More information is available in the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.